# Diagonalizable $3×3$ Matrix with columns $\overrightarrow{v}$, $\overrightarrow{2v}$, and $\overrightarrow{3v}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ $\in$ $\mathcal{M_{3\times3}}$ has columns equal to $\overrightarrow{v}$, $2\overrightarrow{v}$, and $3\overrightarrow{v}$ for some $v \in \Bbb{C^{3}}$ and $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Apparently, this is true. Any help conceptualizing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: what can the Jordan blocks of a $3 \times 3$ matrix look like? (There's a chance this hint is useless because you don't have the background knowledge - there's a reason we ask you to provide context here.)

Comment: By direct evaluation, the Eigenvalues are $0,0,v_x+2v_y+3v_z$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $u_1=(1,1,-1)^t$ and $u_2=(-1,2,-1)$ are linearly independent and $Au_1=Au_2=0$. Therefore, $u_1,u_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ for the eigenvalue $0$.
If $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue $r\neq0$, then there is a vector $u_3$ such that $Au_3=ru_3$. Moreover, $u_3$ must be linearly independent with $u_1,u_2$, since it is an eigenvector for a different eigenvalue.

Therefore, $A$ diagonalized in the basis $u_1,u_2,u_3$.